# With flutter printing package, how do I print a PDF from a URL?

Tags: pdf, flutter, printing

I am using the printing package in flutter: https://pub.dev/packages/printing

The documentation shows how to create PDFs from scratch. I already have a PDF at a URL. Is there a way to retrieve it and print it with the package? Or is there an alternate method with another package?

Answer (score 5):

I have tried the following ways to achieve the printing feature:

- **Directly get the remote data bytes**
  With the popular package [printing](https://pub.dev/packages/printing)

```
var data = await http.get(url);
await Printing.layoutPdf(onLayout: (_) => data.bodyBytes);
```

But I found that this way will have the printing area disorder issue when printing a roller size paper (POS printer)

- **Sharing (alternative of the first one)**
  Use the sharePdf function

```
var data = await http.get(url);
await Printing.sharePdf(bytes: data.bodyBytes, filename: 'my-document.pdf');
```

This one needs an additional step to print (click the 'functions' icon of browser then print)

- **View it from the browser and print it natively**
  Check out this package [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

if (await canLaunch(url)) {
  await launch(url);
}
```

This one needs an additional step to print (click the 'functions' icon of browser then print)

- **Download the remote file and save it, use the flutter_pdf_printer package.**
  Use this package [flutter_pdf_printer](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pdf_printer) and [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider)

```
var data = await http.get(url);
final output = await getTemporaryDirectory();
final file = File('${output.path}/your_file_name_${new DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch}.pdf');
await file.writeAsBytes(data.bodyBytes);
await FlutterPdfPrinter.printFile(file.path);
```

*** this package will have channel registrant [issue](https://github.com/cadaniel/flutter_pdf_printer/issues/3#issuecomment-806264501), please run `flutter clean` after installation ***
This package is a little bit outdated, but it works for me to print with a roller 80 size pdf. It uses the Swift UIKit package, which has good compatibility.

#### Summary

My scenario is to print a roller 80 size pdf with infinite height, the printing package doesn't work for cuz it cannot preview the pdf properly. So I changed to the last way to print, which works for me. If you just print an A4 or a regular size PDF, the printing package is still a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

From the plugin documentation To save the pdf file using the path_provider library:

```
    final output = await getTemporaryDirectory();
final file = File("${output.path}/example.pdf");
await file.writeAsBytes(pdf.save());
```

print the document using the iOS or Android print service

```
await Printing.layoutPdf(
  onLayout: (PdfPageFormat format) async => pdf.save());
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your string url to URI, please make sure you are adding http

http: ^0.13.4

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse('Your link here');
                        http.Response response = await http.get(uri);
                        var pdfData = response.bodyBytes;
                        await Printing.layoutPdf(onLayout: (PdfPageFormat 
                        format) async => pdfData);
```