# How to load an existing pdf and print using printing in flutter

Tags: pdf, flutter, printing

I've been been trying to print an existing pdf file which is in sd card. 
So i added **printing** package to my flutter project to print pdf files.

[Printing package link](https://pub.dev/packages/printing/versions/1.0.6)

I checked their documentation and i can't find a way to load and print pdf.

Fyi, i can create a pdf from image, text or whaetever it is and pass it to the Printing function. That works as anticipated.

```
final pdf = Document();

pdf.addPage(Page(
      pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
      build: (Context context) {
        return Center(
          child: Text("Hello World"),
        );
      })
);

await Printing.layoutPdf(onLayout: (PdfPageFormat format) async => pdf.save());
```

Any help to load existing pdf and print would be appreciable

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally find a way to print pdf using printing plugin.

You can directly print pdf by giving the online pdf url

To do so, just use the following dart snippet

```
http.Response response = await http.get('http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf');
var pdfData = response.bodyBytes;
await Printing.layoutPdf(onLayout: (PdfPageFormat format) async => pdfData);
```

Don't forget to import http plugin

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

Thanks everyone for the help

Comment: Is it possible to show only 1st page of PDF file?

Comment: I am answering myself: property:  pages: [1,2,3] will solve the problem

Answer (score 4):

Including the other answers:
BTW, I have an another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59691468/with-flutter-printing-package-how-do-i-print-a-pdf-from-a-url/66793618#66793618) regarding this topic

- **Directly print from a URL**

```
var data = await http.get(url);
await Printing.layoutPdf(onLayout: (_) => data.bodyBytes);
```

- **SharePdf function**

```
var data = await http.get(url);
await Printing.sharePdf(bytes: data.bodyBytes, filename: 'your-document.pdf');
```

This one needs an extra one step to print.

- **View from the browser**
  Use this package [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher), open in a browser view, then print it

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

if (await canLaunch(url)) {
  await launch(url);
}
```

This solution needs an extra one step to print as well.

- **The flutter_pdf_printer package.**
  Use this package [flutter_pdf_printer](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pdf_printer) and [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider)

```
var data = await http.get(url);
final output = await getTemporaryDirectory();
final file = File('${output.path}/your_file_name_${new DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch}.pdf');
await file.writeAsBytes(data.bodyBytes);
await FlutterPdfPrinter.printFile(file.path);
```

*** this package will have channel registrant [issue](https://github.com/cadaniel/flutter_pdf_printer/issues/3#issuecomment-806264501), please run `flutter clean` after installation ***
This package is a little bit outdated, but it works for me to print with a roller 80 size pdf. It uses the Swift UIKit package, which has good compatibility.

Welcome add comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
final Uint8List bytes = await pdf.save();
Printer? pri = await Printing.pickPrinter(context: context);
await Printing.directPrintPdf(
printer: pri!, onLayout: (PdfPageFormat format) async => bytes);
```

With this code you can view your printer and print the document for this i use
[printing 5.9.3](https://pub.dev/packages/printing)

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://pub.dev/packages/native_pdf_view) will help you to load the pdf on the screen.

```
import 'package:native_pdf_view/native_pdf_view.dart';

Widget pdfView() => FutureBuilder<PDFDocument>(
  // Open document
  future: PDFDocument.openAsset('assets/sample.pdf'),
  builder: (_, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      // Show document
      return PDFView(document: snapshot.data);
    }

    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      // Catch 
      return Center(
        child: Text(
          'PDF Rendering does not '
          'support on the system of this version',
        ),
      );
    }

    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  },
);
```

To print the pdf file, use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pdf_printer) package.

```
 await FlutterPdfPrinter.printFile(file.path);
```

[Here](https://github.com/cadaniel/flutter_pdf_printer/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart) you can find a sample.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I've checked the **native_pdf_view** plugin and it helped me to show pdf on the screen. But still i can't find an exact way to print existing pdf. I've also checked the 2nd link and it seems like they create pdf and print from there. But this is not what i want. I already have pdf and i just need to print right away. It is okay if i can't preview pdf before printing

Comment: @HussainBadusha I have updated the answer with an easy solution.

Comment: thanks. I tried **FlutterPdfPrinter.print** but error pops out saying **The method 'print' isn't defined for the class 'FlutterPdfPrinter.print'** I find that there is another function called **printFile**. But that too returns error

Comment: did you check the sample code available with the package?

Comment: i have a question: Where should the printer be configured? With the above code, how will it find out which printer to choose to print?

Comment: It will open the default platform handler

Comment: I wanted to check but before that all of a sudden i ran into a new issue with kotlin error [check this screenshot for error](https://i.postimg.cc/wMsHc44R/flutter-print-kotlin-error.png) I think that it doesn't support my current kotlin version

Comment: Regarding printer configuration, it is a wireless printer in our office network and i want to connect to the same network and print from my flutter app. This is my goal.

Comment: @HussainBadusha open the android folder in android studio and try to resolve.

Comment: @Darish yes i tried to solve it by changing the kotlin version from 1.3.50(current) to 1.2.71(needed by flutter print plugin). And in terminal of android studio, after using **cd android**, i ran the **gradlew build**. Still the same error comes

Comment: change gradle version to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1' to force android studio to use kotlin plugin with version 1.2.71.

Comment: @Darish Finally it works. I was changing directly kotlin version. That was the issue. By the way, i tested it in new sample flutter app and it worked. But in actual flutter app, i have many plugins added in pubspec.yaml. So do you have any idea **changing gradle version would affect other plugins functionality**?

Comment: gradle plugin has very good backward compatibility, so usually it would not make any issue.

Comment: Accept my answer if you think it helped you.

Comment: @Darish I happy to mark it as an answer. But before that, as i feared, i got a problem after changing gradle version with **permission_handler** plugin. here is the [error message](https://i.postimg.cc/qMwk87r2/flutter-print-kotlin-error-1.png) There are few more plugins which need to be built after this one here is the list of [plugins](https://i.postimg.cc/SKq7HV5B/plugins-for-fe.png) Please bear with me i'm posting too many links as i a noob to both android and flutter

Comment: @Darish thanks for your help. I don't know what to do now with that. So i'll look for other permission plugins

Comment: keep the plugin that uses the latest gradle version, and open issue on the plugins that are not yet up to date.

Comment: in your case, open issue on FlutterPdfPrinter repo.

Comment: Yes i already created an issue there but in the meantime i need to look for flutter_pdf_print alternatives

Comment: @HussainBadusha did you found any solution for printing pdf?